# How to get custom fields at registration?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm using djnago User model and registration system. I've created another Model for custom user infos. I want to show this fields at registration step.
Here are my codes:

My model:

```
    def upload_image_location(instance, filename):
        return "%s/%s" %(instance.id, filename)


    class Profile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True,verbose_name="Açıklama")
        city = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True,verbose_name="Vitrin Fotoğrafı")
        avatar = models.FileField(blank=True,null=True,upload_to=upload_image_location,verbose_name="Vitrin Fotoğrafı")

        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.username


    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)'
```

Here is my forms.py

```
    class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
        first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='İsminizi giriniz.', label="Ad")
        last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Soyisminizi giriniz.', label="Soyad")
        email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Geçerli bir mail adresi giriniz.', label="Mail")

        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', )
```

Here is my views.py part:

```
    class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
        form_class = SignUpForm
        success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
        template_name = 'registration/signup.html'
```

Now I want to get city, description and avatar fields at registration step. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you want to ask for that information at the registration step, the straight forward approach would be to have a customer user model in place, inheriting `AbstractBaseUser`.

Then, you'll explicitly set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your `settings.py` file to point to the new model.

More detailed info can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is to redirect User after registration to a profile form where he can update other details, in your case city, description and avatar

Comment: Thanks but this is not exactly what I want.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this:-

in ur forms.py:-

```
 from .models import Profile

 class ProfileForm(models.ModelForm):
   ''if u want to add attributes''
      class Meta:
           model=Profile
           fields = ['description','city','avatar']
```

in ur views.py:

```
   from .forms import ProfileForm
   from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

   def profile_form_view(request):
      if request.method=='POST':
         user = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
         profileform = ProfileForm(request.POST)
             if user.is_valid() and profileform.is_valid():
                  user.save()
                  profile = profileform.save(commit= False)
                  profile.user = user
                  profile.avatar = request.FILES['avatar']
                  profile.save()
                  return reverse_lazy('login')
             else:
                 user = UserCreationForm()
                 profileform = ProfileForm()

             return render(request,'your html file',{'user':user ,
                                                      'profile':profileform})
```

try this it may sort out ur prblm :)